# Can I data-bind my knockout mvvm to the mvc html.textboxfor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I use data-binding in an html control like this

```
<input data-bind="value: firstName" />
```

but can I do it in an html helper textbox for?
something like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.lastName , data-bind="value: lastName")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can add attributes by using the `htmlAttributes` parameter.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.lastName , new { data_bind="value: lastName"})
```